# Image conversion : RGBA to RGB

Tags: c++, rgb

assuming i had RGBA (32 bits) output from frame-grabber, with alpha channel unused (values retained while filled by frame-grabbers), is there any effective conversion method to RGB (24 bits) ?

I am dealing with 5 MegaPixels streaming images so speed does matter too.
keep in mind that data in alpha channel can be discarded.

Comment: What exactly *do* you mean? 24-bit RGB implementations use 32 bits and ignore the alpha channel, so you **do not need to make any changes, but only if you want to discard the alpha channel ie. if it is unused by your source, too**

Comment: I'm writing a hardware abstraction layer for my company.
the data consumer only takes 24 bits RGB, and modifying them is the last thing we wanted to do.

so i'm left with the option to create another 24bit rgb buffer, and place the conversion result into it.

Comment: @yeenfai : Okay, it can be different for hardware...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy the data and skip the unused alpha bytes.

If speed is important for you, you may want to use SSE or MMX and use the built-in bit-shuffling instructions. That is usually a bit faster than ordinary c-code.

5 megapixels doesn't sound like that much of data unless you have to do it at 100fps though.

Answer (score 3):

Just copy RGB bytes and discard alpha channel (1 byte). Possible optimizations will be hardware specific. For instance Intel has special color conversion functions in [IPP library](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ipp/ippi/ippi_ch6/ch6_Intro.html).

Comment: Yeah, just skip the alpha bits and copy the rest. If you're working with hardware, it'll probably have an internal buffer, use that.